# How does one use Maven in WSL from IntelliJ running on Windows?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am building and running my Maven package from WSL. I have gone through the process of setting up display forwarding and running IntelliJ graphically on WSL.  This is fine for looking at code and searching for things.

However, this is not ideal for developing. As a more performant and permanent alternative, I am setting up IntelliJ in the home OS, Windows, and configuring the IDE to use the WSL resources.

I've successfully configured the JDK based on WSL, but it looks like I'll need to set up my MAVEN_HOME to point to the MAVEN_HOME on WSL, which is in the home folder rather than the mounted c drive. I already have the hacky solution involving symlinks.

What I am looking for is a way to leave the MAVEN_HOME folder in the home drive of WSL, and point my IntelliJ maven tool to that home folder.

How would I do that?

Comment: Do you mean that it's not possible to select folder from WSL as your MAVEN_HOME?

Comment: @y.bedrov yeah, pretty much. Unless I am missing something. I wound up copying everything into a mounted windows drive and symlinking the drive in WSL. I still have to use the windows java on the windows side.  But since Maven "just works" on the WSL side, I'm able to provision all the dependencies from WSL. That would be the "hacky" solution. I don't see any way to connect to WSL to get at the home drive, which isn't, as far as I know, a location in windows.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your exact setup and maybe share a few screenshots so we can better understand the nature of the issue? For a setup you're describing everything should be on WSL (Maven, Maven Local repo, JDK, your Project), only IDEA should be running on Windows. Also, by MAVEN_HOME are you referring to the Maven distribution files location or the .m2 folder with Maven Local repo and extracted wrappers?

Comment: @romanv-jb The main issue here is that "everything running on WSL" with IDEA running on Windows seems impossible. I'd have no problem doing anything on Pycharm or CLion; the problem here is while I'm familiar with Jetbrains, I'm new to Java. So if that helps you understand where the knowledge may be missing, I'll explain what I've tried.

Comment: @romanv-jb I've set up IDEA on WSL, exporting the display from WSL. This became a non starter because while it worked great at some point last year, lately the GUIs have been unusable, with mangled components and offset mouse coordinates. I assume Windows has made changes. Then I set up IDEA on Windows and was able to get almost everything integrated with WSL.  However, I ran into an issue where to get Java running on Windows, I had to use the Windows Java.  The WSL java simply did not compile on the Windows side, with many deep and basic error messages displaying from fetched (correct) src

Comment: @romanv-jb instead, what I had to do was use windows JAVA on IDEA.  Then I copied my Maven folder with all 3rd party sources fetched via WSL (which has all my access tokens/keys) command line compilation on the Linux side to the Windows' expected maven folder location.  Next, I symlinked that location to the maven location in WSL.  Now, I can compile in Windows and everything works. --BUT-- I've done this hack, which (to motivate) on its own is fine, but collectively is yet another windows hack I have to remember (meaning I'll forget and retrace my steps later).  So I've put up this question.

Comment: @romanv-jb I think the solution might be one of two things that may or may not already be implemented: 1) I somehow used WSL Java in Windows IDEA incorrectly, and that was a user error OR 2) there is some option to synchronize my WSL maven folder to windows, and maintain the sync (existing or easy enough to make). When asking this question, I figured I was asking about (2) and whether it exists, but maybe I screwed up at option (1).